# Setting button DOM google maps

Tags: google-maps, dom, button, google-maps-api-3

I have a problem setting up an html button that must ask for geolocation, show and put the marker in the correct place:

First, I started loading the method:

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init_map);

Then:

```
function init_map() 
{
var lima = new google.maps.LatLng(-12.043333,-77.028333);
var browserSupportFlag =  new Boolean();
var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map_canvas');

map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, 
{
    zoom: 2,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    center: lima
});

var distanceWidget = new DistanceWidget(map, initialLocation);

google.maps.event.addListener(distanceWidget, 'position_changed', function() 
{
    displayInfo(distanceWidget);
}
);

google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('get_latlng'), 'click', get_location(map,distanceWidget.get_marker()));
```

}

The HTML:

```
<button type="button" id="get_latlng">Get your current location</button>
```

But what it does, is that the listener loads itself, what I want it to do is that it executes when I click the button.

Comment: Where is the get_location function?

Comment: Can you post a live link to a map that demonstrates the problem? It's hard to debug from code snippets, you don't always know where the problem started.

Answer (score 0):

wrap the call into a function:

```
google.maps.event
 .addDomListener(document.getElementById('get_latlng'), 
                 'click', 
                 function(){get_location(map,distanceWidget.get_marker());});
```